# Ofstream overwrite files contents when executed more than once

Tags: c++, file

Suppose I declared a file `ofstream myFile`. Now I only want to create this file once, and when I execute this line a second time I don't want to overwrite the file and create a new one?

Comment: Have you considered picking a different file name?

Comment: It would not be practical with what im working on. Im working on a CGI webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a one-file one-function setup (such as a log) you may consider using a static variable.

For example:

```
static ofstream* mylogger::outfile = new  ofstream ("log.log");
```

Just too be cool from main function you should push a clean up function

```
atexit (mylogger::closePointers);
```

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating the `ofstream`?

Comment: To expose it to other functions so that it is easier to close.

Answer (score 1):

```
ofstream myfile("filename",ios::app);
```

but this will keep on appending to the file. In the beginning if the file is not present, would create it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ofstream myFile;
```

It doesn't create a file at all. You've not passed the filename to the constructor. If you pass it, it will create the file if the file already doesn't exist. That also means, if you don't want to overwrite the file second time, then pass a different argument instead.

Comment: If I create and open the file in append mode, will it still overwrite the file a second time?